# How to fetch json file in MEAN?

Tags: json, express, mongoose, mean

I am new in MEAN.I have json content inside database.Need to fetch the content and want to show at the front

Here is the json collection which I have taken from terminal

```
athira@athira-Inspiron-3558:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> use ehsjson
switched to db ehsjson
> db.ehsjson.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ddfc8758749dac677fe0af"), "glossary" : { "title" : "example glossary", "GlossDiv" : { "title" : "S", "GlossList" : { "GlossEntry" : { "ID" : "SGML", "SortAs" : "SGML", "GlossTerm" : "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym" : "SGML", "Abbrev" : "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef" : { "para" : "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso" : [  "GML",  "XML" ] }, "GlossSee" : "markup" } } } } }
>
```

Here is my code I have tried to fetch the data

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ehsjson');
var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', mongoose.Schema({

glossary: {
    title: String,
    GlossDiv: {
        title: String,
        GlossList: {
            GlossEntry: {
                ID: String,
                SortAs: String,
                GlossTerm: String,
                Acronym: String,
                Abbrev: String,
                GlossDef: {
                    para: String,
                    GlossSeeAlso: Array
                },
                GlossSee: String
            }
        }
    }
}


}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

app.get('/api/employee', function(req, res){
    Employee.find(function(err, ehsjson)
    {
        console.log(ehsjson);
        if(err)
        {
            res.send(err);
            console.log("error"+err);
        }
        res.jsonp(ehsjson);
    });
     //res.jsonp(Employee.ehsjson());
});
```

But its returning null object.

Please help to find out the mistakes

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map the JSON content with the Employee object. But the JSON content has different data so it won't be matched with Employee object. That's why you are getting null.

Insert the content like this and try it. It will work.

> db.employee.find()
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("58deb49ddf74cfbde91cf804"), "name" : "test", "dept" : "dept", "area" : "area", "status" : "status", "contact" : "contact", "salary" : "122" }

Comment: I have updated the Employee object. But still its showing null

Comment: I have tested your code and created the collection name as "employee" and got it working. Anyway, you got it working by specifying the collection name.

Comment: var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', mongoose.Schema({
  },{collection: 'ehsjson'}));
like this also its working

Answer (score 0):

got it nothing it just add the collection name

```
var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', mongoose.Schema({
     glossary: {
        title: String,
        GlossDiv: {
            title: String,
            GlossList: {
                GlossEntry: {
                    ID: String,
                    SortAs: String,
                    GlossTerm: String,
                    Acronym: String,
                    Abbrev: String,
                    GlossDef: {
                        para: String,
                        GlossSeeAlso: Array,
                    },
                    GlossSee: String
                }
            }
        }
    }


    },{collection: 'ehsjson'}));
```